# Como fazer um update na minha aplicação em WPF depois de instalado?

Tags: c#, wpf, instalador

Eu já achei vários programas que criam um instalador para a minha aplicação, mas eu estou preocupado quando eu precisar fazer atualizações no sistema, eu precisava que fosse algo automático, quando o usuário logasse, o sistema checaria se tem atualizações, se houver o próprio sistema baixa a atualização e atualiza. Alguém tem algo do tipo ou alguma dica?

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma tecnologia da Microsoft chamada [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t71a733d.aspx). Você precisa estudar e se familiarizar com o seu funcionamento. O Visual Studio já possui tudo o que você precisa pra gerar instalador da sua aplicação com o ClickOnce. Eu utilizo em um sistema que fiz para um cliente e funciona muito bem.